# Django and whitenoise - caching "too much"

Tags: django

I am using Whitenoise to serve static files (images, css, js) for a Django site. Now my problem is that the static files seem to be "cached to much"(?) when working locally. Description of actions:

0. Initially my static files are served correctly
1. I edit a file in `static/`
2. I run `./manage.py collectstatic` (which correctly identifies one updated file).
3. When going to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` my browser consistently shows the old stale version of the file. I have even tried completely removing the generated `staticfiles/` folder - and the browser still seems to be able to dig out an old version of the file?

This is when running locally in debug mode. Do not have a consistent understanding of how it is in production, but I think it works better (as it should?) there.

My configuration:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ....

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # My apps 
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
...
...
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    ("js"  , BASE_DIR / "static/js"),
    ("css" , BASE_DIR / "static/css"),
    ("img" , BASE_DIR / "static/img")
]
```

I guess the problem is that I do not really understand the `Whitenoise` model - slightly frustrating as this should be quite simple??

**Update**: I have tested this in Firefox with Ctrl-Shift R to reload the page, and got the old version. But when actually deleting the browser cache explicitly things work. feels a bit excessive that I have to manually wipe the browser history - but I can live with that.

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache? It could also be cached in the browser.

Comment: With `CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage` I believe whitenoise should be doing proper cache management.  I would check the browser developer tools settings and check the related requests.

Comment: OK thanks: What would be *proper cache management* in this case?

Comment: whitenoise should be making a hash of the files in static and provide a unique hash included in the filename so that when it's updated the new file is used.  The resulting file the browser sees should look something like this: `/css/layout-user-Index.1d319d5e.css`.

Comment: If the hash isn't updated, I suspect that `collectstatic` isn't running as expected.  May be the app where the `static` is being updated isn't included properly.  Isn't in INSTALLED_APPS, or the updated file not being reached by directories defined in `STATICFIELS_DIRS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a hard reload works, then the browser is most likely caching the parent request (rendered html result).

So if you have an endpoint, `/myendpoint/`, that returns a rendered template, where the template contains the static file reference handled by *whitenoise* , `css/mycss.{hash}.css`, the parent request is being cached and the browser doesn't see the updated static file reference.

Django has some tools that help dealing with browser-side caching.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/cache/#controlling-cache-using-other-headers

If you want to make sure the client always get's the latest page you can use the `never_cache` decorator.

```py
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache

@never_cache
def myview(request):
    ...
```